# Adding inline tags within text node in javascript

Tags: javascript, createelement, createtextnode

Hi there this might be easy but I am new and just learning I need help with 2 problems.

First, when creating element using `document.createElement()` how to add class or id to that element?

---- found a solution for this problem of `className = ""` or `id=""` by adding a variable to differentiate the data originated from the array which I added and named id  ----

Second, using `createTextNode()` to avoid using the innerHTML how to add the line breaker tag within?

Lets say I have an array of `items = [{id: "item-1", name: "apple", price:1} , {id:"item-2" ,name : "mango", price:3}];`

and I want to go through them with:

```js
let data = document.getElementById("items-data"); 
items.forEach(item => {
                   let container = document.createElement("div"),  //here i want to add a defined id for further use
                       itemData = document.createTextNode(
                                  `item name : ${item.name} price: ${item.price}`); //here i want to add the br
    container.appendChild(itemData);
    container.id = item.id;
    data.appendChild(container);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

```js
let base = document.querySelector(".base");

let items = [{
  id: "item-1",
  name: "apple",
  price: 1
}, {
  id: "item-2",
  name: "mango",
  price: 3
}];

items.forEach(item => {
  let container = document.createElement("div"), //here i want to add a defined id for further use
    itemData = document.createTextNode(
      `item name : ${item.name} price: ${item.price}`); //here i want to add the br
  container.appendChild(itemData);
  container.appendChild(document.createElement("br")); // <-- Add the line break to the node element
  container.id = item.id;
  base.appendChild(container);
});
```

```html
<div class="base"></div>
```

Comment: It worked but I have append part of the phrase the append the <br> then another part then the <br>